# Is Fisher's exact test good for this use?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I have a table that looks something like this:

|  | group 1 | group 2 | group 3 | group 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| region1 | 50 | 217 | 340 | 53 |
| region2 | 32 | 23 | 36 | 42 |
| :------- | :-------: | :-------: | :-------: | -------: |
| male | 40 | 200 | 36 | 42 |
| female | 42 | 40 | 340 | 53 |
| :------- | :-------: | :-------: | :-------: | -------: |
| city | 45 | 42 | 63 | 34 |

The table has more demographic values, but this is the general look of it.

I want to see if a group number is significantly more, less, or equally represented in each demographic variable when compared to the same demographic variable of the total population. Is Fishers exact test a good way to do this?

Comment: What are group members? Group 1, 2, ...? Is this count data? Can you separate your data further into region 1 + male, region 1 + female, ...? When you say equally represented do you mean having similar frequency with the other groups?

Comment: @user2974951  The groups are clusters from cluster analysis that wasn't based on the demographic data. I want to compare the demographics of the different groups to the demographics of the entire population, which is just the summation of all of the groups. When i say equally represented, I mean a similar frequency to the entire population's demographic data. I want do this for each group. For example, I'd like to be able to say that group 3 is significantly more female than the entire population, etc for each demographic variable for each group. I'm not sure what you mean by region 1 + male

Comment: Note that with the data presented in your question, you don't need a test to say that group 3 has certainly a higher proportion of women than all the other groups. By the way, if you were to conduct an omnibus test like a chi-squared test, you should conduct it on two-way tables, not on the aggregated table presented in your question. That is, one test on the "region vs. group" table, a second test on "gender vs. group", etc. You should also have a look at that: https://scholarworks.umass.edu/pare/vol20/iss1/8/

Comment: Make sure the pre-processing using cluster analysis does not create a circularity in the analysis and its interpretation.

Comment: @J-J-J When you say I don't need a test to say that group 3 has certainly a higher proportion of women than all the other groups, do you mean a simple percentage is fine? I've thought about this, but I feel like having a p-value from some test would back up my results in a mathematical way. I was worried I should use Fisher's exact test since I only have four groups for each demographic variable

Comment: @FrankHarrell The cluster analysis was done using variables entirely separate from the demographics data., so I think I'm good on that. I was hoping to look to see if the demographic data significantly correlated with the group number, but it's been a challenge to find the absolute best way to do this. I've tried a few things and nothing seems to feel like it does the job. I don't have confidence in the chi squared test because I only have 4 groups, but I've read Fisher's exact isn't the best test to use in general. A factor that really makes me struggle is that the groups are different sizes.

Comment: @anni Not just the percentages, also the counts. I wouldn't say that if you had only a few observations. Just by looking at the counts of the "group vs. gender" table, one can tell that it's unlikely that the distribution of "females" is similar in group 3 and in other groups. Of course, you can run a test to double check, but it is a bit redundant: you will get a very small p-value. By the way, a chi-square test would be perfectly appropriate here. Why do you think that having 4 groups is problematic for a chi-squared test?

Comment: @J-J-J I'm worried a chi-sqaured test wasn't good because i only have 4 observations for each of the demographic variables. I first thought each individual in a group counted as an observation for the given demographic, but I was reading that this is not true--maybe i got that wrong. For the chi squared test, should I look at the percentage of each demographic variable  in each group and compare that to the total percentage for each demographic variable? Or should I just see if group number and each demographic variable correlate-I worry about doing this because the groups are different sizes.

Comment: @anni An observation is an individual. You have 793 observations in total in the "gender v. group" table. So for example, there are 376 observations in "group 3", and 36 observations at the intersection of "group 3" and "male". Also, never use percentages with a chi-square test of independence, always use counts. // Generally, it sounds like the things you are reading about chi-squared tests are confusing you a bit. You could ask a new question about what are some good introductory resources about chi-squared tests, or a question to clarify things you are not sure to understand about it.